# CXF JAXB Databinding issue - java.io.Serializable is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

Tags: jaxb, cxf

I have following code

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SamplePojo {
    private Serializable id;
    private String name;

    public Serializable getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Serializable id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and a simple webservice interface,

```java
@WebService
public interface SampleManagementService {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "samplePojo")
    public SamplePojo update(@WebParam(name = "samplePojo") SamplePojo pojo) throws SampleException;
}
```

I am using CXF-2.3.6 and `org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS` to generate WSDL from java code. When I ran the command

```
java2ws -verbose -o sample.wsdl -wsdl -frontend jaxws com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SampleManagementService
```

I got following exception

```
cxfJavaToWSDL:
     [java] java2ws -verbose -o sample.wsdl -wsdl -frontend jaxws com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SampleManagementService
     [java] java2ws - Apache CXF 2.3.6
     [java]
     [java] May 29, 2012 4:51:48 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
     [java] INFO: Creating Service {http://sample.webservice.cxf.test.com/}SampleManagementServiceService from class com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SampleManagementService
     [java] Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
     [java]
     [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractServiceFactory.createService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:80)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:101)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:110)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:45)
     [java] Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:341)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:442)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:682)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:505)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:242)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:202)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
     [java]     at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractServiceFactory.createService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:78)
     [java]     ... 8 more
     [java] Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
     [java] Adapter com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SerializableAdapter is not applicable to the field type java.io.Serializable.
     [java]     this problem is related to the following location:
     [java]             at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter$DEFAULT, value=class com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SerializableAdapter)
     [java]             at private java.io.Serializable com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo.id
     [java]             at com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo
     [java]             at private com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.jaxws_asm.Update.samplePojo
     [java]             at com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.jaxws_asm.Update
     [java] java.io.Serializable is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
     [java]     this problem is related to the following location:
     [java]             at java.io.Serializable
     [java]             at private java.io.Serializable com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo.id
     [java]             at com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo
     [java]             at private com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.jaxws_asm.Update.samplePojo
     [java]             at com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.jaxws_asm.Update
     [java] java.io.Serializable does not have a no-arg default constructor.
     [java]     this problem is related to the following location:
     [java]             at java.io.Serializable
     [java]             at private java.io.Serializable com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo.id
     [java]             at com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo
     [java]             at private com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.SamplePojo com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.jaxws_asm.Update.samplePojo
     [java]             at com.test.cxf.webservice.sample.jaxws_asm.Update
     [java]
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
     [java]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
```

I tried to create `SerializableAdapter` but no luck. Can anybody please let me know what's the correct way to handle `Serializable` parameter passing?

Answer (score 3):

That won't work. `Serializable` can't be handled by JAXB, the binding engine that CXF uses when handling the actual conversion between Java and XML.

To fix, you have to decide whether you want the `id` property in the XML at all. If you don't, just tagging the getter with `@XmlTransient` will make things work. However, if you *do* want an id, then you have to decide how it is going to be mapped to a string (something which would be far simpler if the field was a concrete class and not just any old arbitrary serializable thing). If you have a conversion to/from `String` that works well, you just change your property to be a string property or make a fake property:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) // Note the change here too!
public class SamplePojo {
    private Serializable id;
    private String name;

    @XmlTransient
    public Serializable getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Serializable id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public String getStringId() {
        return id.toString(); // Or whatever...
    }
    public void setStringId(String id) {
        this.id = IdFactory.getIdFromString(id); // Or whatever...
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Donal, I tried the way you suggested, but our problem is the Serializable id is not always be mapped with String. It could be Long, Integer, String, Date or any custom Serializable type. I am stuck on this issue and I don't have any workaround so far.

I modified id to java.lang.Object but the generated schema return value of type org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl and I really don't have clue which Object to convert to.

Any help around this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  You will need to specify a value type that is mappable (`String` in the example below) and then provide the necessary conversion logic:

**SerializableAdapter**

```
package forum10798310;

import java.io.Serializable; import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class SerializableAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Serializable>{

    @Override
    public Serializable unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Serializable v) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**SamplePojo**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to link in the `XmlAdapter`.

```
package forum10798310;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SamplePojo {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SerializableAdapter.class)
    private Serializable id;
    private String name;

    public Serializable getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Serializable id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Blaise, your answer won't work in this case, still I get the same exception.